# How to update user meta for multiple meta_key in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-key

I'm trying to update multiple meta_key for user in WordPress

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, array( 'nickname' => $userFirstName, 'first_name' => $userFirstName, 'last_name' => $userLastName , 'city' => $userCityID , 'gender' => $userGenderID) );
```

but it is not working. How can we update multiple meta_key for user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$user_id = 1234;

$metas = array( 
    'nickname'   => $userFirstName,
    'first_name' => $userFirstName, 
    'last_name'  => $userLastName ,
    'city'       => $userCityID ,
    'gender'     => $userGenderID
);

foreach($metas as $key => $value) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $value );
}
```

So instead of passing your array to [`update_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) which only accepts string arguments for `$meta_key`, loop over the array and call `update_user_meta` for each key/value pair in the array.

EDIT:

WordPress doesn't give a built in way to update multiple metas at once.  Part of the reason for using their built in function is because filters and hooks can be registered to operate on the meta information.  These won't be called if you update them directly.

That said, you can try something like this (code untested):

```
$columns  = implode(" = '%s', ", array_keys($metas)) . " = '%s'";
$values   = array_values($metas);
$values[] = $user_id;
$table    = _get_meta_table('user');
$sql      = "UPDATE $table SET $columns WHERE user_id = %d";
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($sql, $values)
);
```

Comment: i'm trying to update all the meta data fields using one update

Comment: There is no way to do that built-in for reasons mentioned in my edit, but there is some code you can try to modify to do what you want.

Comment: Bear in mind that `update_user_meta()` will also insert the value if it doesn't exist. Running an `UPDATE` query on the DB directly will only update existing values.

Comment: `wp_update_post` does take `meta_input`. [It's just a loop internally](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/631f08096bea41722a67e6b2e70d50ae0e2d3508/wp-includes/post.php#L4518-L4522) though, so there's no performance benefit.

Answer (score 5):

just try to add the value with the same meta key,and remember to set the third value to false just like

```
add_user_meta( $user_id , $meta_key , $value1 , false );
add_user_meta( $user_id , $meta_key , $value2 , false );
add_user_meta( $user_id , $meta_key , $value3 , false );
```

then when you get user meta with the meta key ,it will return like:

```
['$value1','$value2','$value3']
```

Comment: Still valid in 2020!

Answer (score 0):

> $userid = get_current_user_id();
> $name = ;
> $surname = ;
>
> wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $userid, 'first_name' => $name,
> 'last_name' => $surname ) );